# How to install all the packages under JuliaStats?

Tags: julia

I want to install all the packages under JuliaStats, but none of the followings is working:

```
julia> Pkg.add("JuliaStats")
ERROR: unknown package JuliaStats
 in macro expansion at ./pkg/entry.jl:53 [inlined]
 in (::Base.Pkg.Entry.##2#5{String,Base.Pkg.Types.VersionSet})() at ./task.jl:360
 in sync_end() at ./task.jl:311
 in macro expansion at ./task.jl:327 [inlined]
 in add(::String, ::Base.Pkg.Types.VersionSet) at ./pkg/entry.jl:51
 in (::Base.Pkg.Dir.##2#3{Array{Any,1},Base.Pkg.Entry.#add,Tuple{String}})() at ./pkg/dir.jl:31
 in cd(::Base.Pkg.Dir.##2#3{Array{Any,1},Base.Pkg.Entry.#add,Tuple{String}}, ::String) at ./file.jl:59
 in #cd#1(::Array{Any,1}, ::Function, ::Function, ::String, ::Vararg{Any,N}) at ./pkg/dir.jl:31
 in add(::String) at ./pkg/pkg.jl:100

julia> Pkg.add("julia-stats")
ERROR: unknown package julia-stats
 in macro expansion at ./pkg/entry.jl:53 [inlined]
 in (::Base.Pkg.Entry.##2#5{String,Base.Pkg.Types.VersionSet})() at ./task.jl:360
 in sync_end() at ./task.jl:311
 in macro expansion at ./task.jl:327 [inlined]
 in add(::String, ::Base.Pkg.Types.VersionSet) at ./pkg/entry.jl:51
 in (::Base.Pkg.Dir.##2#3{Array{Any,1},Base.Pkg.Entry.#add,Tuple{String}})() at ./pkg/dir.jl:31
 in cd(::Base.Pkg.Dir.##2#3{Array{Any,1},Base.Pkg.Entry.#add,Tuple{String}}, ::String) at ./file.jl:59
 in #cd#1(::Array{Any,1}, ::Function, ::Function, ::String, ::Vararg{Any,N}) at ./pkg/dir.jl:31
 in add(::String) at ./pkg/pkg.jl:100

julia> Pkg.add("juliastats")
ERROR: unknown package juliastats
 in macro expansion at ./pkg/entry.jl:53 [inlined]
 in (::Base.Pkg.Entry.##2#5{String,Base.Pkg.Types.VersionSet})() at ./task.jl:360
 in sync_end() at ./task.jl:311
 in macro expansion at ./task.jl:327 [inlined]
 in add(::String, ::Base.Pkg.Types.VersionSet) at ./pkg/entry.jl:51
 in (::Base.Pkg.Dir.##2#3{Array{Any,1},Base.Pkg.Entry.#add,Tuple{String}})() at ./pkg/dir.jl:31
 in cd(::Base.Pkg.Dir.##2#3{Array{Any,1},Base.Pkg.Entry.#add,Tuple{String}}, ::String) at ./file.jl:59
 in #cd#1(::Array{Any,1}, ::Function, ::Function, ::String, ::Vararg{Any,N}) at ./pkg/dir.jl:31
 in add(::String) at ./pkg/pkg.jl:100
```

I was not able find any help regarding this issue on the [homepage](http://juliastats.github.io/) of JuliaStats. Any help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[JuliaStats](https://github.com/JuliaStats) is not a library of packages.
It is an organization of people who together maintain collection of packages.

You don't **want** to install ***all*** of their packages.
Several of them are deprecated -- replaced by newer packages from the same org.

You want to install the package that you want, for your task.
The package manager will workout what other packages that one needs, and download them for your.

Eg you want to sample from a Trucated Gausian Distribution?
Then you'll want [Distributions.jl](https://github.com/JuliaStats/Distributions.jl).
Install that by running: `Pkg.add("Distributions")`

This will also install a number of other packages from Julia Stats: StatsFuns.jl, StatsBase.jl, and also from elsewhere Calculus.jl,  SpecialFunctions.jl.
Because these packages are required for Distributions.jl to run.